# Returning/Displaying Integer in Handlebars JS Template?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I need to use a Handlebars JS template to display some data in an app I am creating. So for example my method returns the number of tickets that are open...now to display this integer how would I do it in the template?

In my JS file I tried something like this:

```
    this.switchTo('list', {
        count: this.count
    });
```

Where 'list' is my template and count is my integer variable. I was able to display contents in a template if it was a JSON format but I don't really know what to do if its just an integer...

Anyways this is what I used to display a string with JSON format:

```
<ul class="ticket_list">
    {{#each tickets}}
        <li>
            {{this.subject}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}   
</ul
```

Is the solution to create a string formatted like JSON and then send it to the template?

Any advice would be awesome because I am pretty stuck on this...

Comment: Well the way the apps for Zendesk work is that I need to switch to the template I need to use. So I'm switching to a template 'list' from the default layout. So basically I need to send and array, I can't just display a single value? The tickets, was just an example of how I used a JSON object before in a template, but right now I just need to display count which is an integer....should I just create an array with 1 element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the data that you send into a Handlebars template has to match the structure of the template. So, if you have this template:

```
<ul class="ticket_list">
    {{#each tickets}}
        <li>
            {{this.subject}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}   
</ul>
```

then your data needs to look like this:

```
// #each implies an array
tickets: [
    { subject: ... }, // this.subject implies that you have an object with a subject key
    { subject: ... },
    ...
]
```

So if you wanted to use that template to display a single value then:

```
this.switchTo('list', {
    tickets: [ { subject: this.count } ]
});
```

Or you could use a different template:

```
<!-- whatever HTML wrapping you need... -->
{{count}}
```

and

```
this.switchTo('count_template', {
    count: this.count
});
```

Comment: hmm, I just tried those two options but neither seems to work for me. I get nothing printed out, basically what you mentioned as using {{count}} was my first idea but I just can't seem to get that working...

Comment: @TudorHofnar: Are you sure `switchTo` works the way you think it does? The Handlebars stuff works: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CwyLY/

Comment: Well I'm going by this documentation: http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/templates.html I could be completely wrong but thats just how I understood it. To be honest I think what you are saying is right, because that's how I thought it would work, but for some reason it does not want to...I'll keep trying

Comment: "this.switchTo is used to change the contents of <section data-main /> with the template we name, which is where this.switchTo('list') comes in.

In our example we pass in data we want to use in list.hdbs
"

Comment: Waiiiit, I think its my count variable that is not working correctly or has a wrong value. The code you posted works!! Thanks!